# Keep table cell width from growing larger than content

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a way to do this *without* using Javascript.

Let's say I have a `<table>`, and I don't know the potential width of the content that populates the first column. The `<table>` has `width:100%` so that the rest of the columns can resize as neccssary, but I'd like to keep the first column with a *fixed* width so that it doesn't grow larger than the content.

Is this possible without Javascript?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Dynamic content column of unknown width</th>
        <th>Some other column that is allowed to grow/shrink</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
        <td>195383 ...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that by setting the width of the dynamic content column to `1px`, the column width will be fixed to the width of the content in the column, and still allow the other column to grow/shrink with the table.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might consider using `min-` and `max-width`  (together) as an alternative; this gives the column a little *room for manoeuvre*. Andy.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

To set a fixed width for the first column:

```
tr th:first-child, tr td:first-child {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but remember that we don't know the potential width of the fist column. I've figured it out though.